# Supposedly random API returning same thing over and over

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, discord.js

Im making a discord bot that shows a random image from https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php
The code is simple

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'belikebill',
    description: 'Gives a random "Be like Bill" meme',
    async execute(message) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '$belikebill') {
            message.channel.send('https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1')
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried messing around with axios requests and putting it an embed but nothing changed.

How can i randomize this?

Answer (score 4):

It may be that the image at `https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1` is being cached by the clients, similar to what's happening in the below snippet:

```html
<img src="https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1">
<img src="https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1">
```

Try adding a random query string to the end, to ensure new requests are made each time:

```
message.channel.send('https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1&random=' + Math.random())
```

```html
<img src="https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1&random=0.123">
<img src="https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1&random=0.456">
```

If you're worried about repeated random numbers, keep track of an index instead:

```
let index = 0;
module.exports = {
    name: 'belikebill',
    description: 'Gives a random "Be like Bill" meme',
    async execute(message) {
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '$belikebill') {
            message.channel.send('https://belikebill.ga/billgen-API.php?default=1&extra=' + index++)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Date.now()` or `performance.now()` makes a better cache-buster IMO. `Math.random()` isn't guaranteed to not repeat

Comment: @Phil An issue with `Date.now` is that it may well repeat if called twice synchronously. `Math.random` might repeat, but not often at all (much, much less often than the API will repeat naturally). I guess if it's an issue, one could keep track of a persistent index that gets incremented on each call instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you tell I've been bitten by random number _"uuids"_ before 